# Click a tab when a modal event is triggered

Tags: javascript, tabs, modal-dialog

I want to auto-open the first tab when the modal shows (The first tab with "names=tabs"). Right now, I have to manually click the tab to show content.

### Here is the HTML tabs and modals markup

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l3">
    <div class="card">
        <a class="modal-trigger" href="#abc">
        <div class="card-image">
        </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="abc" class="modal">
        <div class="row"><h4></h4></div>
        <div class="row">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab29" />
                <label  for="tab29"></label>
                <div id="tab-content29" class="tab-content">
                  <p></p>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab30" />
                <label for="tab30"></label>
                <div id="tab-content30" class="tab-content">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab31" />
                <label for="tab31"></label>
                <div id="tab-content31" class="tab-content">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab32" />
                <label for="tab32">Contact</label>
                <div id="tab-content32" class="tab-content">

                </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- Container
```

And here is the JS that triggers a modal

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.modal-trigger').leanModal(
        {
        dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
        opacity: .4, // Opacity of modal background
        in_duration: 150, // Transition in duration
        out_duration: 150, // Transition out duration
        }
    );
    });
```

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe if you could provide a jsFiddle of your problem. _LeanModal_ does not support callbacks but there might be a workaround to this.

Comment: The modal window has tabs for navigation. I  want the first tab to be active when the modal window opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *LeanMdal* does not have a callback method you can probably achieve this by creating a separate click event like this

```
$('.modal-trigger').on("click", function(){
    $('ul.tabs li:first').click();
})
```

Comment: `first-child` actually.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to add whatever classes control tab visibility straight into the HTML. leanModal doesn't seem to support any sort of callbacks or events.